# 2003 Ford Mustang 3.8l v6 oil pan removal

Tags: ford, mustang, oil-pan

[image]changing out the rod bearings on my first car. I read on ALLDATA that I have to lower the front subframe to get the oil pan out from under the car because it is right above the subframe. However, it says to loosen the two upper bolts but I can't find them. Behind the wheels I see four bolts (two on driver side and two on passenger side) but having the four lower bolts removed and those four bolts I thought were the upper bolts loosened almost all the way doesnt lower the subframe for some reason. So my question is does anyone know where the two upper bolts are, or at least any typical places to look for? Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: you'd be better served by pulling the engine and putting it on a stand to do the rod bearings. can you take pictures of the subframe? I'd suspect you have to pull the mount bolts as well.

Comment: A picture would be worth a thousand words on this.

Comment: Yes pulled the mount bolts to raise the engine, and I will be taking pictures later today.

Comment: from the picture it kind of looks like the bolts are near the mounts or around the strut tower.

Comment: i thought that it was the ones behind the strut but i loosen those and the subframe doesnt budge. Also, ALLDATA says that theres only two. I found four.